# Restart Program So My C++ game is replayable

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a c++ program for a tic tac toe game.
The game must have a game counter for the number of wins 
each player has as long as the number of ties. The issue 
I am having is that I can't seem to get the board to clear,
so when it reaches the end of one game, the board clears
the X's and O's. Any help I can get, I would appreciate greatly!

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void display_board();
void player_turn();
bool gameover();
int xwins, owins, ties;

char turn;
bool draw = false;
char board[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

int main()
{
    cout << "Tic Tac Toe Game\n";
    cout << "Player 1 [X] --- Player 2 [O]\n";
    turn = 'X';
    char board[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

    while (!gameover())
    {
        display_board();
        player_turn();
        gameover();
    }

    if (turn == 'O' && !draw)
    {
        display_board();
        cout << endl << endl << "Player 1 [X] Wins! Game Over!\n";
        xwins++;
    }
    else if (turn == 'X' && !draw)
    {
        display_board();
        cout << endl << endl << "Player 2 [O] Wins! Game Over!\n";
        owins++;
    }
    else
    {
        display_board();
        cout << endl << endl << "It's a draw! Game Over!\n";
        ties++;
    }


}

void display_board()
{
    cout << "---------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0][0] << "  |  " << board[0][1] << "  |  " << board[0][2] <<"      Player 1 wins "<<xwins<< endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" <<endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[1][0] << "  |  " << board[1][1] << "  |  " << board[1][2] <<"      Player 2 wins "<<owins<< endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[2][0] << "  |  " << board[2][1] << "  |  " << board[2][2] <<"      Ties "<<ties<< endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
}

void player_turn()
{
    int choice;
    int row = 0, column = 0;

    if (turn == 'X')
    {
        cout << "Player 1 turn [X]: ";
    }
    else if (turn == 'O')
    {
        cout << "Player 2 turn [O]: ";
    }
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: row = 0; column = 0; break;
    case 2: row = 0; column = 1; break;
    case 3: row = 0; column = 2; break;
    case 4: row = 1; column = 0; break;
    case 5: row = 1; column = 1; break;
    case 6: row = 1; column = 2; break;
    case 7: row = 2; column = 0; break;
    case 8: row = 2; column = 1; break;
    case 9: row = 2; column = 2; break;
    default:
        cout << "You didn't enter a correct number! Try again\n";
        player_turn();
    }

    if (turn == 'X' && board[row][column] != 'X' && board[row][column] != 'O')
    {
        board[row][column] = 'X';
        turn = 'O';
    }
    else if (turn == 'O' && board[row][column] != 'X' && board[row][column] != 'O')
    {
        board[row][column] = 'O';
        turn = 'X';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The cell you chose is used! Try again\n";
        player_turn();
    }

}

bool gameover()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Check for a win
    {
        if ((board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2]) || (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i]) || (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]) || (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Check for draw
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != 'X' && board[i][j] != 'O')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    draw = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not avoid global variables and have a `play_game` function that can be called multiple times...

Comment: Your sample code does not have anything in it to reset the board. That said, try taking all your initialization code and moving it into an init() function. If you move everything, you should be able to call it when you want to restart. Then show us your code *with the reinitializetion called* so we can diagnose what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues with your code :

```
while (!gameover())
{
    display_board();
    player_turn();
    gameover();
}
```

You do not need the gameover() inside the loop. You are already checking for it in the condition.

Also, you are not resetting your global variables after each instance of the game. Add another while / do- while loop which runs until a particular condition. Within this loop, add your main functionality. And reset your global variables (draw, board and turn ) for each instance of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
do{
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: row = 0; column = 0; break;
        case 2: row = 0; column = 1; break;
        case 3: row = 0; column = 2; break;
        case 4: row = 1; column = 0; break;
        case 5: row = 1; column = 1; break;
        case 6: row = 1; column = 2; break;
        case 7: row = 2; column = 0; break;
        case 8: row = 2; column = 1; break;
        case 9: row = 2; column = 2; break;
        default:
        cout << "You didn't enter a correct number! Try again\n";
    }
}
while(choice<1 || choice>9);
```

because if user enter any other value its calling `player_turn();` again so that it will work `recursively` (Calling same function inside function).

No need to call `gameover();` again inside the loop as you are checking `while(!gameover())`.

After match is draw you need to set value if array to 1,2,3... and call funtion `display_board();`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly then there are 2 problems:

1) You need to find a place for win and tie counter.

```
bool gameover()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Check for a win
    {
        bool row_match    = (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2]);
        bool column_match = (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i]);
        bool diagonal_match = (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]) || (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]);

        if (row_match || column_match || diagonal_match)
        {
            bool x_wins = (row_match && board[i][0] == "X") || (column_match && board[0][i] == "X") || (diagonal_match && board[1][1] == "X")

            if (x_wins) xwins++;
            else owins++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//Check for draw
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != 'X' && board[i][j] != 'O')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ties++;
    draw = true;
    return true;
}
```

2) You need to clear the board.

```
do
{
    display_board();
    player_turn();
} while (!gameover);
clearboard();

void clearboard()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            int val = 3 ** row + col + 1;
            board[row][col] = itoa (val);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if does not solve your problem or if I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding how your clearboard function is working. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Hi Christopher,
Here, clearboard function, is just replace "X" and "0" with integer value ranging from 1-9, which is the reset state of the board.

I guess, you want to know how variable "val" is giving the correct integer value for the board entries. We can see the board as a 3x3 matrix. With rows 0-2 and colums 0-2. If you manually compute the value of a entry in board, given its row and column value, you will find that variable val is correctly computed.

Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: what is the meaning of itoa?

Comment: itoa is to convert integer to string. As the board variable stores the character and the value computed is int. So itoa is there to bridge the gap.

Comment: do you know what library it is in? Is it in iostream?

Comment: I am getting an error message saying too few arguments

Comment: This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.

Use:
  board[row][col]  = (char)(((int)'0')+val);

Comment: Christopher if my solution works for you, please accept my solution.